# I want to pause execution until input is submitted without using Ask or

Tags: input

I am developing a Yahtzee-type PC game. I would like the program to pause execution until the player has selected one, two, or all three checkboxes and clicked on "Clicked when done." (See below.) However, I have tried looking here and at Wolfram's various help resources without any success.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance I can get with this.

Thanks!

Joe

[image]

===================

## I hope this does a better job of describing my desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if I understood you right. But this runs when you click the button and holds once you start the selection process

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;

 If[state == "RUN",
  tick = Not[tick];
  c++;
  Pause[.1];
  Grid[{
    {" I am running now ", c}, 
    {"5", p5},{"2", p2},{"1", p1}}]
  ,
  c = 0;
  Row[{" I am not running, waiting for button...... "}]
  ],

 Grid[{
   {"Select die to hold"},
   {"5", Checkbox[
     Dynamic[p5, {p5 = #; state = "STOP"; tick = Not[tick]} &]]},
   {"2", Checkbox[
     Dynamic[p2, {p2 = #; state = "STOP"; tick = Not[tick]} &]]},
   {"1", Checkbox[
     Dynamic[p1, {p1 = #; state = "STOP"; tick = Not[tick]} &]]},
   {Button["Click when done", tick = Not[tick]; state = "RUN"]}
   }],

 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{state, "STOP"}, None},
 {{p5, False}, None},
 {{p2, False}, None},
 {{p1, False}, None},
 {{c, 0}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

Comment: Nasser, I did not know how to provide additional information without "answering" my own question so I edited my original question with the question framed somewhat differently. Thanks! Joe

Comment: @JoeColetta Thanks for the update to your question. I am not clear how you want to use the `i` counter there. Are you planning to store all the results that is why you are using counter `i`? Or you just want the current result to show? If so, why do you need `i`?  I think what I showed above you should be able to adopt to your code. Only difference is that you using images and random selection of dice. I do not have the images of dice to show. If something still not clear in the code I showed, feel free to ask.

Comment: Nasser, your comments and questions have helped me understand the applicability of your program in my program. I'm going to think about this for a couple of hours and then I think my next reply will be to say I understand and to thank you for your help and answer your last few questions